# Print text file with folder file names

Tags: windows-7, windows-command-prompt, text

So i have been tasked with getting folder and file names for a portable hard drive. Currently I'm not sure how to go about doing this I know the standard command prompt way to go about it, but let's say it's over a million files spread across about 20,000 folders on a terabyte hard drive. So I'm curious if anyone can point me into a starting direction for this. In a nut shell what I would like to do is execute a .bat file that would create a text file with the directory as a header then all files in that folder listed below that directory name but have this cycle through the entire hard drive if this is possible? Or if some one knows if there is a better way to do this, just looking for a direction to start with. 
C:/test/folder Alpha 
filename112.text
filename221.tif
filename331.gif

C:/test/folder Bravo
filename1.text
filename2.tif
filename3.gif

C:/test/Folder Charlie
filename112.png
filename221.aspx
filename331.jpeg

Comment: Are you sure with Bat ? What about Powershell ?

Comment: Yea I have no preference I'm sure powershell will be better to handle this.

Comment: Ok, so please provide a sample of the text file file you would like to get.

Comment: I have updated the question to show what the text file should look like, what I need is super simple as far as information pulled and printed

Comment: Ok, thank you. What about subdir, if any ?

Comment: there shouldn't be any subdirectories. but if there is subdirectories can be treated just like directories as long as the full file path is printed.

Comment: `$d='';gci -R|%{$s=$_.DirectoryName;if ($d -ne $s){write "\`n$($s)";$d=$s};write $_.Name}` annoying PowerShell one-liner.

Comment: Not for nothing, but you can do this from the command prompt with a single line: `dir /s >c:\files.txt` - Just substiture the appropriate source and destination drive letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PowerShell

```
$LastDirectory = ""
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach {
    if ($LastDirectory -ne $_.DirectoryName) {
        $LastDirectory = $_.DirectoryName
        Write "`n"
        Write $_.DirectoryName
    }
    Write $_.Name
} | Out-File foundFiles.txt
```

You can see it on screen by removing the `| Out-File foundFiles.txt` bit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't match your expected output formatting, but a much simpler way to do this is:

```
dir /s /b /a | sort > files.txt
```

Output will look like:

```
C:\test\folder Alpha\
C:\test\folder Alpha\filename112.text
C:\test\folder Alpha\filename221.tif
C:\test\folder Alpha\filename331.gif
C:\test\folder Bravo\
C:\test\folder Bravo\filename1.text
C:\test\folder Bravo\filename2.tif
C:\test\folder Bravo\filename3.gif
C:\test\folder Charlie\
C:\test\Folder Charlie\filename112.png
C:\test\Folder Charlie\filename221.aspx
C:\test\Folder Charlie\filename331.jpeg
```